# Application approval submission failing with "We're sorry. Something went wrong. Please try again later. The backend responded with an error"

Tags: nest-api

I understand this isn't a typically appropriate question for Stack Exchange but the Nest customer service has basically no information whatsoever on developer support, and the Works with Nest support contact form recommends using Stack Exchange tagged with nest-api. Anyway, I have created an application in the developer portal I need to submit for a user limit increase, and I have been unable to submit the form for the last 3 days. I receive a generic error that says:

> We're sorry. Something went wrong. Please try again later. The backend responded with an error

As I said, I contacted every customer support outlet Nest offers and have yet to get any assistance. If anyone has encountered this error or has the proper avenue to reach out to Nest's developer support team, please let me know. Thank you in advance, again I apologize for the narrow scope of this question.

Comment: We probably can't help with customer support issues here, but if you have a technical question, ask that here. There may be other Nest developers who can help, but they will need to know what the problem is.

Comment: Ah, if it is just a user limit increase, that doesn't sound like it is a code issue. Try tweeting them, maybe? We have a long-standing frustration on Stack Overflow that profit-seeking entities try to dump their support responsibilities onto volunteer communities, and I hope that is not happening here! Good luck.

Comment: (Long shot: try a different computer or browser, in case there is something in your machine that upsets their website).

Comment: Yea it is definitely the situation that they are referring developers here when they have technical questions. The confirmation email from their contact form specifically says to ask here, because their "developers actively answer questions"  here. I did try other computers and browsers etc. I was hoping I would reach someone here who has either encountered this issue or knows who to contact. This was a last ditch effort to get some valid support. Twitter is not a bad idea. Thank you for your replies.

Comment: "profit-seeking entities try to dump their support responsibilities onto volunteer communities" - that is exactly what Nest is doing. They have no other avenues of support code-wise and minimal support installation-wise.

Comment: Maybe try toggling permissions for the client or delete that client and make a new one.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else runs into this issue, my final resolution was to re-create a second application on a different developer account, and then migrate my web service to use the new application's client secret, API tokens etc.. Albeit a huge hassle, the submission (using the exact same form data as before) worked on the new application.